# Conditional Kolmogorov compexity of string concatenation

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

In what follows $K(x|y)$ is conditional Kolmogorov complexity, $xx$ is $x$ concatenated with itself. It appears to me that $K(xx|yy)=K(xx)$ should be true for infinitely many strings $x$ and $y$. In fact, it seems this should be true "generically" (in some appropriate sense). How hard is this to show (if true)?

Comment: What [description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Definition) does your K use? ​ ​

Comment: I believe you mean one must fix some specific universal machine in the definition of K? I assumed this choice will be irrelevant for the answer, won't it?

Comment: If the choice is in fact irrelevant, then I don't see any easier way of showing that than also showing what the answer is. ​ ​

Comment: If you generate two random strings for x and y, with finite probability your statement holds. I think. Maybe. Possibly.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the concatenation changes anything, as $K(xx) \le K(x) + C$ for some constant C (dependent on the language).

Comment: Thanks TLW. Your first comment is basically my reasoning behind the question. I'll post a separate question on that issue: I wonder how one may go about filing in the details.